# Send a variable with a URL and get a variable with Wp query

Tags: wp-query, query-variable, date-query

I want to send a variable with a url and get the value and insert that value to a variable.

```
<a href="domain/newsletter-by-year?year=2020">GO TO THE NEWSLETTER FROM 2020</a>
```

ang get it in this url

https://domain/newsletter-by-year?year=2020

This is my wpquery

```
    /* Template Name: newsletter_by_year */

$year = $_GET["year"];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'news-letter',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $year,
        ),
    ),
);

$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

but im getting a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response but the problem was the name of the variable I changed it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the page template is applied to the correct page and you are accessing the correct URL

and then go to the **Settings > Permalink**  and save permalinks one or two times.

That should clear the older rewrite rules and make the new page template work instead of sending you to the 404 page

Comment: Thanks my friend, I just had to changed the variable its very weird but it worked.